# .NET RSA data signing, are my assumptions correct?

Tags: c#, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I've been digging into the .NET `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace, specifically the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class. It has two methods using in signing data, `SignHash()` and `VerifyHash()` and I have a few questions regarding the usage of this class and methods.

**1**) When instantiated, `RSACryptoServiceProvider` creates a keypair, like so:

```
// 1 = RSA compatible. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dh4wac4.aspx
CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters( 1 );
cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoFlags;
rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider( 2048, cspParams ); // rsa is a class member
rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
```

Then the private and public keys can be saved to disk using the following code:

```
public void WriteKeys( FileInfo file, bool includePrivateKey )
{
    using( FileStream fs = new FileStream( file.FullName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None ) ) {
        string xml = rsa.ToXmlString( includePrivateKey );
        byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( xml );
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String( b );
        b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( base64 );
        fs.Write( b, 0, b.Length );
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

**Q**: Is there anything that can prevent the subsequent loading of the public key on a client computer at a later time (exempting file access rights etc.), using code such as this:

```
private void ReadKeyFromFile( FileInfo keyFile )
{
    byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes( keyFile.FullName );
    string base64 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( b );
    byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String( base64 );
    string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( b );
    rsa.FromXmlString( xml );
}
```

**Q**: If specifying Csp flag CspProviderFlags.UseArchivableKey instead of CspProviderFlags.None, the loading of the file fails (at rsa.FromXmlString()) with a CryptographicException "Invalid flags specified.", why is that? The 'Achivable' sound just like what is I want, no?

**Q**: Is there anyway of creating a `RSACryptoServiceProvider` without also creating a new keypair (as I will load an existing key shortly after) ?

**2**) According to MSDN, the two methods `SignHash` and `VerifyHash` can be used to sign a hash of some arbitrary data, using the private key, then be verified using the public key to ensure the validity of the data.

**Q**: What if I distribute the public key with my application (embedded resource or base64 encoded string etc.) to validate a license key that has been hashed and signed using my private key - can I be certain that no one else can generate license keys that are considered valid by the application (assuming I keep the private key private)? After all, that is what the public/private keys are for, are they not?

Example signing code:

```
using( SHA1 sha = SHA1.Create() ) {
    byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash( data );
    byte[] signature = rsa.SignHash( hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID( "SHA1" ) );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An attacker can simply decompile your code and insert his own public key.

Comment: An awful lot of questions in 1. Don't fret about the (extra) keys generated, you have all the tools to load/save/create keys. And you are correct about the signing process, but like @slaks commented as a license it's a heavy lock on a cardboard door.

Comment: Well, yes of course. Such is the problem with any software, no matter the language. Even obfuscating the code and encrypting the public key will not be 100% secure against a determined attacker; they can even disable the entire validation, which probably would be easier. Now, my question is not about what a hacker can or cannot do, it is about the cryptography mechanism.

Comment: There's pretty much no point to doing what you suggest, Per.

Comment: @AndrewBarber and why's that?

Comment: Because you aren't understanding the purpose of a Public key. It is to give to someone who *wants* to use it to verify the source of a message. A license hacker would not want it, making it useless for precisely the people you think you want to use it for.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Well, **I** want to use it to verify the license key. As I wrote above, there's nothing I can do stop a hacker modifying the application, short of poking them with the sharp end of a stick.

Comment: Then **you** use it. But don't think for an instant that it is making your license verification process secure in the least, because it isn't.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4340/discussion-between-per-and-andrew-barber)

Comment: No thank you. Not interested.